# What do you call it when someone misunderstands a homonym?

Tags: errors, homonyms

I once ran across a term for the error of misunderstanding the meaning or sense of a word because one doesn't know exactly what the word is. For example, someone mistakenly thinks that the phrase is "tow the line" rather than "toe the line." Can anyone tell me what this type of misunderstanding is called?

Comment: 'Toe' and 'tow' are homophones but not homonyms according to some authorities: 'In the strictest sense, a homonym must be both a homograph and a homophone. So say many dictionaries. However, other dictionaries allow that a homonym can be a homograph or a homophone.' ( https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/homonym-homophone-homograph/ )

Comment: Does it happen to little kids a lot? It happened to me pretty often  when I was very young. It'd generated a lot of fun.

Answer (score 21):

As Edwin Ashworth has already mentioned, your example are homophones, not homonyms. A homonym    looks the same and sounds the same. *Stalk* (follow) and *stalk* (stem of a plant) are homonyms. *Read* (a book) and *reed* (plant) are homophones.

In the strictest sense, there is sometimes a distinction drawn between 'true' homonyms as above, and polysemes where the words have a shared etymology and are technically the same word with differing meanings, such as *mole* (furry thing in a hole) and *mole* (a spy).

Alternatives to mondegreens -

[*malapropism*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=malapropism) - *(the unintentional misuse of a word by confusion with one that sounds similar*

or *[eggcorn](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/)* if the phrase retains an unintentional meaning, *signaled out* instead of *singled out* for example.

Comment: +1 for eggcorn. I suggest editing your post to move the meat of your answer (malapropism and eggcorn) to the beginning and de-emphasize the commentary on homophones.

Comment: In particular, de-emphasize the “your example are homomphones” comment.

Comment: Eggcorns usually rely on the speaker’s accent, as well.

Answer (score 14):

These errors are called [*mondegreens,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) especially in the context of misheard lyrics.

Comment: @J.R. that'll make you fly like a cheese stick - http://www.kissthisguy.com/fly-like-a-cheese-stick-far-east-movemen-misheard-19778.htm

Comment: @J.R. there's a bathroom on the right if you want some privacy.